# Number of Involuntory Keys in Permutation Cipher

Tags: encryption, permutation

I've came with the following problem from the **Theory and Practice** book by Stinson-Paterson. It states the following:

2.17

> (a) Prove that a permutation $\pi$ in the Permutation Cipher is an
> involuntory kei iff (if and only if) $\pi(i) = j$ implies $\pi(j) =
> > i$, for all $i,j \in \{1,...,m \}$.
>
> (b) Determine the number of involutory keys in the *Permutation
> Cipher* for $m = 2,3,4,5, $ and 6.

I've proved the first item, showing that the indices of the $x's$ and $y's$ remain the same, however I don't have any hint to determine the second item b, this is, I'm not sure of the role of the key in this type of cipher; any clarifications, indeed one clear answer would be good.

Comment: 2, 4, 10, 26, 76, see http://oeis.org/A000085 , the first one; identity and the cross, you need to try...

Comment: Indeed, I want an absolutely clear answer, otherwise it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Indeed, it makes sense. Do you want us to count all 76 for you? here is the third; identity, the first element fixed the other is swapped, the second element fixed the other swapped, and the third is fixed and others are swapped. Determination requires hand and observation, deriving formulae is hard. See https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PermutationInvolution.html

Answer (score 1):

> Involutions are in one-to-one correspondence with self-conjugate permutations (i.e., permutations that are their own inverse permutation)

The series is given in [oeis A000085](http://oeis.org/A000085).

The [formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PermutationInvolution.html) for the number of involution permutations on $n$ letters is;

$$I(n) = 1 + \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2 \rfloor} \frac{1}{(k+1)!} \prod_{i=0}^k \binom{n-2i}{2}$$

**A little hand calculation**

First of all, identity permutation $\varepsilon$ is always an involution. Here we will use [one line notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#One-line_notation).

- $m =2 $ then $\varepsilon = (1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ are the involutions.
- $m =3 $ then $\varepsilon = (1,2,3)$, $(1,3,2)$,$(3,2,1)$, and $(2,1,3)$ are the 4 possible.
- $m =4 $ then $\varepsilon = (1,2,3,4)$ and

  - fix first $(1,a,b,c)$ then we have 3, by previous case;  $(1,2,4,3),(1,4,3,2),(1,3,2,4)$
  - fix second $(a,2,c,d)$ then we have 2, $(3,2,1,4),(4,2,3,1)$ ( one existed in the previous case)
  - fix third $(a,b,3,d)$ then we have 1, $(2,1,3,4)$
  - fix fourth $(a,b,c,4)$ then we have 0; all existed before.
  - fixed double then $(4,2,3,1)$
  - doubles $(3, 4, 1, 2),(2,1,4,3)$

---

**A Sagemath code for 5**

```
p = Permutation([1, 2,3,4,5])
for i in range(0,factorial(5)):
    if p == p.inverse():
        print(p)
    p = p.next()
```

With output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 4]
[1, 2, 4, 3, 5]
[1, 2, 5, 4, 3]
[1, 3, 2, 4, 5]
[1, 3, 2, 5, 4]
[1, 4, 3, 2, 5]
[1, 4, 5, 2, 3]
[1, 5, 3, 4, 2]
[1, 5, 4, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 1, 3, 5, 4]
[2, 1, 4, 3, 5]
[2, 1, 5, 4, 3]
[3, 2, 1, 4, 5]
[3, 2, 1, 5, 4]
[3, 4, 1, 2, 5]
[3, 5, 1, 4, 2]
[4, 2, 3, 1, 5]
[4, 2, 5, 1, 3]
[4, 3, 2, 1, 5]
[4, 5, 3, 1, 2]
[5, 2, 3, 4, 1]
[5, 2, 4, 3, 1]
[5, 3, 2, 4, 1]
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: As we can see, the determine doesn't necessarily mean using hand calculations. Using computers we can determine, too..